# Tomcat failed to install after running script through user data of Ubuntu EC2 instance on AWS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, amazon-ec2, tomcat

This is the script I added to the user data:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk -y
sudo apt install tomcat10 tomcat10-admin tomcat10-docs tomcat10-common git -y
```

It's an Ubuntu 22.04 AMI on AWS and it returns the following code after I SSH and do a systemctl status:

`Failed to start tomcat.service: Unit tomcat.service not found.`

I've tried a lot of things after doing a lot of googling and youtubing and nothing seems to work. Any idea what I may have done wrong?

EDIT:
I initially had the script trying to install open jdk 8, I changed it to jdk 11 since 8 may not be compatible with Ubuntu 22.04. I was also trying to install tomcat 8. I tried 9 and now 10. All of this with new instances. When none of that worked, I tried to install manually. I tried the step by step guide I found [here](https://www.coachdevops.com/search?q=install+tomcat+ubuntu+ec2)! and it didn't work either.

Deleted the whole thing and tried to install manually in the /opt/ folder this time, still didn't work.

(My SG allows ports 22 and 8080 btw)

Whenever I do try to install via Instance Connect and sudo su in the home directory, it actually just work. I just have to to /bin/ and execute startup.sh and it actually lets me access when I type myip:8080. But as soon as I exit and go to GitBash to ssh, systemctl gives the same error.

Comment: “I've tried a lot of things” could you show some of them?

Comment: Just edited my post and explained some of the things I tried. I hope this makes it a little clearer.